# Can we open an android apk in the browser?

Tags: android, cordova, selenium, phonegap-plugins, android-testing

Hi People I have an apk file that is made using phonegap and I need to test it using selenium so that I can get the id's of the components in the application and feed them into the scripts, can you tell that is there any way to open the apk file in the browser so that the process becomes easier or is there any app that can do that? any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

APK is just a ZIP-file, so you can rename it into .zip and open in a browser. 
Though, you cannot add files into APK this way easily, because the content of APK is signed and aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible first unzip your apk and remove "onDeviceReady"(Related to phone gap events)  event and then try in browser

Comment: How to remove this property of the android apk can you enlighten me about that

Comment: and also if you can detail the process of opening the application on the browser I will be grateful to you :)

Comment: what is your OS ( windows or Linux or Mac)

Comment: ok rename your apk as .zip then extract files you will get assets folder after follow above process